# Make a type of table data into integers for if/else statement after web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to make a table dataset into a integer for a if/else statement, problem I'm having is that after i get the numbers i need i can't figure out a way to convert it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://us.tamrieltradecentre.com/pc/Trade/SearchResult?ItemID=3790&SortBy=Price&Order=asc"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

select = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "bold hidden-xs", "data-mins-elapsed": True})
converted_time = ([s["data-mins-elapsed"] for s in select])
```

So here i can print the numbers i need from "converted_time" but i don't quite understand how it's getting them with this for loop.

```
"converted_time = ([s["data-mins-elapsed"] for s in select])"
```

So what i need to do is make the numbers i get from converted_time and make them into separate integers and check and see if any of them are less than whatever number i put. P.S Sorry new to web scraping and Python and struggling to find solution's to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I am not quite clear about your questions. It seems you are trying to achieve a complicated task using list comprehension. Well, if the task was heavy,  just use a traditional for loop and add the result into a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are almost there!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://us.tamrieltradecentre.com/pc/Trade/SearchResult?ItemID=3790&SortBy=Price&Order=asc"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

select = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "bold hidden-xs", "data-mins-elapsed": True})
```

This part I didn't touch. you have sucessfuly obtained the needed html data from the page, now all we need to do i convert it to integer array as per your description:

```
integers = []
for s in select:
    integers.append(int(s['data-mins-elapsed']))

# integers -> [1021, 1055, 1027, 1027, 271, 163, 123, 730, 730, 289]

your_number = 300 # put any number you like

for i in integers:
    if i < your_number:
        print(i) # this integer from the list is less than your number, handle it
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked but Can you explain what's going on in "integers.append(int(s['data-mins-elapsed']))" because this is what i don't understand on what and how its doing it and trying to learn for future situations

Comment: s if of type 'bs4.element.Tag', s['data-mins-elapsed'] is a string for example '1027', int method will just cast it to integer so it will become 1027, then it is appended to the integers array

Comment: If you prefer your syntax it will be: integers = [int(s["data-mins-elapsed"]) for s in select]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean converting the list of numbers to integers try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://us.tamrieltradecentre.com/pc/Trade/SearchResult?ItemID=3790&SortBy=Price&Order=asc"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
integers=[]
select = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "bold hidden-xs", "data-mins-elapsed": True})
converted_time = ([s["data-mins-elapsed"] for s in select])
[integers.append(int(i)) for i in converted_time]

if integers[0] == 1:
       print('Value is 1')
else:
    print('Value is not Zero')
```